# google oauth API on server, refresh token not presented on second time

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth

I have next code for google auth

```
use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;
require './vendor/autoload.php';

$application_name = '*****';
$client_secret = '**********';
$client_id = '**********.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$scope = array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds');

            $key = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/the_key.txt');
            $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName($application_name);
            $client->setClientId($client_id);
            $client->setAccessType('offline');
            $client->setAccessToken($key);
            $client->setScopes($scope);
            $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
            $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
            if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

                if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                    $newToken = json_encode($client->getAccessToken());
                    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
                    $client->refreshToken($token['refresh_token']);

json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
                }


                $key = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/the_key.txt'));
```

First time fillin file via oauthcallback via browser, and it works ok, i got refresh token and all works ok.

But when token expires as you see in code i request new via  refresh_token, but in result i didn't get new refresh_token.
Also i forced acces type to offline, and approval prompt to force in Client.php of google-oauth-client(because even if i set it via paramaters it didn't worked).

My script must be executed via cron. So i can't each time receive token manually. Can you help me with this?